# No publications after 2.5 years in PhD

Tags: publications, phd

I started my PhD in solid state physics in 2019 here in US. Due to covid, our labs were closed for about 8months. After that, I could not get any results in 2021 and its been more than 2.5 years into my PhD with no publications.

I wanted to ask the community how concerned should I be. I do freak out sometimes when I think about it. Have other people gone through/going through similar situations? If yes, how did you cope with it?

Comment: What do you have in progress? What are the prospects for upcoming publication?

Comment: Depends on your research field. I know people who graduated with 0 publocations. Don't let this discourage you, but also: work hard and publish something soon.

Comment: Have you talked about this lack of publications with your thesis advisor?

Comment: Would add to @user1271772 point, I know people who graduated with 0 publications, and went on to post-docs. This was a theoretical physics student. Your field is probably key to the answer for this question.

Comment: The last few years have caused many of us to consider freaking out about life in general, much less professional successes. Time for a chat with your advisor, a reset on your mental situation, and a fresh start in the lab working on cool stuff.

Comment: "Have other people gone through/going through similar situations?" Well, yes, practically everyone's research was interrupted in the past two years.

Comment: The answer depends on whether your research is enjoyable and promising and whether you are young and financially happy. If yes to all, then relax and do what @JonCuster says. If no to all, then abort your PhD and do something else.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal for a solid state physics research project to take 4-5 years from start to publication.

> I do freak out sometimes

You should talk to a mental health professional about that.

Answer (score 0):

The last few years were difficult for everyone and you shouldn't put pressure on yourself by comparing your work/outputs to what you could have done before the pandemic. I am not sure whether how universal this is, but in my field (marine science) you can graduate without peer-reviewed publications. So I would first investigate what the rules of your university are regarding graduation and keep working away at your own pace.